# How to Read a text file and insert into mysql tabel if not exist

Tags: mysql, lua

I have text file with values like this :

```
9001,20180501,08:30,12:30;
9002,20180501,08:30,14:00;
9003,20180501,08:30,12:25;
9004,20180501,08:15,12:30;
9001,20180502,08:11,12:32;
9002,20180502,08:24,12:34;
9003,20180502,07:51,13:52;
9004,20180502,08:30,12:30;
9001,20180503,08:30,12:30;
9002,20180503,08:30,12:30;
9003,20180503,08:30,12:30;
9004,20180503,08:30,12:30;
```

and I have a Table called "Person" with values like this :

```
id (INT, PK, A_I)      |   Code   |    Date   |   In   |   Out   |
1                          9001      20180501    08:30    12:30
2                          9002      20180501    08:30    14:00
```

Now I want to read text file line by line and insert into table if "Code" and "Date" col is not exist

I can read text file with LUA line by line into variables and use this code :

```
INSERT INTO Person (id, Code, Date, In, Out) 
VALUES (null, 9001, 20180501, '08:30', '12:30') 
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT Code,Date FROM Person WHERE Code=9001 AND Date=20180501)
```

But it doesn't work !

Does anyway to read text file with MYSQL and insert ?

Comment: Remove the null in the values. You specified the 4 fields you wanted to populate in the insert statement, and the id wasn't one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code violates the *primary key* constraint: it is supplying a `NULL` value for `id`.

Since `id` is auto increment you don't have to specify it at all:

```
INSERT INTO Person (Code, Date, In, Out) 
VALUES (9001, 20180501, '08:30', '12:30') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Code,Date FROM Person WHERE Code=9001 AND Date=20180501)
```

**Edit:** The above doesn't seem to be syntactically correct for MySQL. You can try this query instead:

```
INSERT INTO Person (Code, Date, In, Out) 
SELECT Code, Date, In, Out
FROM 
(
   SELECT 9001 AS Code, 20180501 AS Date , '08:30' AS In, '12:30' AS Out
) as t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Code,Date FROM Person WHERE Code=9001 AND Date=20180501)
```

Comment: @SRR Can you be a little more specific? Do you get any error messages? Do you get unexpected data inserted? Some other unwanted behavior?

Comment: I get a syntax error near "SELECT Code,Date FROM Person WHERE Code=9001 AND Date=20180501)"

Comment: @SRR Did you see the edit I made? The first query is syntactically incorrect in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry , I made a mistake. It's work now. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create unique index with fields

then run inset ignore query it will not allow duplicate data

**ALTER TABLE Person ADD UNIQUE unique_index' (`Code`, `Date`, `In`, `Out`)**

**INSERT IGNORE INTO Person (Code, Date, In, Out) 
VALUES (9001, 20180501, '08:30', '12:30')**